# Dropwizard - Filter gives me 500 server error instead of the response status defined

Tags: jersey, dropwizard

I have a filter - TimeValidationFilter added in for my web service like this:

```
@Override
public final void run(T configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    environment.addFilter(new TimeValidationFilter(), "/*");
    environment.manage(***blablabla***);
    environment.addHealthCheck(***blablabla***);
    try {
        environment.addResource(new BlablaResourceImpl(configuration));
    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

my TimeValidationFilter is just checking whether startTime and endTime is null at this stage:

```
public class TimeValidationFilter implements Filter {

    public final static String START_TIME = "startTime";
    public final static String END_TIME = "endTime";

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        String startTimeStr = request.getParameter(START_TIME);
        String endTimeStr = request.getParameter(END_TIME);

        if (startTimeStr == null || endTimeStr == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);  //line 42
        }
        ........
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

When I have startTime and endTime correctly, the response status from BlablaResourceImpl is giving back the response code 200, 400, 201 all correctly.

When I make a request without startTime and endTime, I am expecting to see 400(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST). BUT instead I get 500 server error and the exception below:

```
WARN  [2013-03-05 13:13:19,490] org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler: /blablabla
! javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: null
! at com.*******.filters.TimeValidationFilter.doFilter(TimeValidationFilter.java:42)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
! at com.yammer.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:29)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1307)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:453)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
! at com.yammer.metrics.jetty.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:200)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:230)
! at com.yammer.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipHandler.handle(BiDiGzipHandler.java:123)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:347)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:47)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:890)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:944)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:634)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:66)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.BlockingChannelConnector$BlockingChannelEndPoint.run(BlockingChannelConnector.java:293)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than throwing a `WebApplicationException`, you want to set an error response code on the `ServletResponse`:

```
HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) res;
if (startTimeStr == null || endTimeStr == null) {
    httpResponse.sendError(400);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Does this mean "throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)" doesn't do what it's supposed to do ?

Comment: Like Coda said on the Dropwizard mailing list, ServletFilters are in a layer below Jersey, and WebApplicationException is a Jersey construct, so ServletFilter doesn't know how to handle the exception, so it 500s.

Comment: As far as unit testing, my usual approach is to mock the HttpServetResponse I pass into the ServletFilter and verify that #sendError was called and mock FilterChain and verify that #doFilter wasn't called.